# Apple Mail Plugin Message Content Body

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, accessibility, apple-mail

I am in the process of developing a Plugin for Apple Mail.
I spend lots of time figuring out how to hook into the undocumented API. But I can't figure out how to access the content of a message.

I can access and manipulate the header alright (from, to, subject)-- but I don't know how to put some text into the actual email message. (I want to place a predefined greeting, like "hello Mr. mail").

Any help is much appreciated. I buy you a beer(or coff
ee, juice, up to you) if you can help me here.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Best regards

Tommy

Comment: I think you are looking for the ```body``` tag or parameter. Load it the same way you load subject or from or to and see what happens.

Comment: Well, it's not that easy. I read and set the header-values from a class called "HeadersEditor" by retrieving an object by value. The body and its very control are nested down the hierarchy in a class called webvieweditor. I am not sure which class-and therefor control it is down the track- nor cant I look into the current value of those objects I retrieve

Comment: Awwwwww - and I was getting thirsty over here for that beer you promised. I wish I could help, but you hacked into some undocumented API and managed to figure out how some portion of it works and now hope somebody can help with the stuff you could not unravel. That is a tall order. However, I am thinking, maybe if you post some code on how you manage to get the header something might click here on SO and somebody can say a ha, to get the message body you need to do it like this or like that ... or maybe I am just curious as to what your hack looks like ...

Comment: Also, just to understand you correctly. You can create a new mail with your own from, to and subject but you can not enter the message body and that is what you are after? Or is it for an existing message, or for both a new and an existing message?

Comment: Hey mate ;) A good starting point to get an overview is:
https://github.com/scr34m/MailReceipt
If you look at @implementation HeadersEditor_MailReceiptPlugin for example.. just add this into the readreceiptClicked-method:
    NSTextField *field = [self valueForKey:@"_subjectField"];
    field.stringValue = @"hello";
You compile the project, copy the mailbundle into the library/mail/bundle directory of mail. Go to settings in mail and select the plugin. after you restart mail you open a new mail and you should see 2 buttons. Click the "R" button and "hello" gets inserted into the subject.

Comment: The problem is, you can create hooks and inject code for all those classes, but its difficult as they have cross references all over the place. I think its a big mess, or I only just didn't get the hang how to work with it yet (what I hope, and I hope you will help me along... 2 beers then, at least)

Comment: Basically... the composeviewcontroller is the thing you compose your new emails---- it has a headers-editor-- which is the header.
I believe the other one should be the WebViewEditor. Could be the EditingWebMessageController as well. I am actually looking for some NSScrollView and a NSAttributedStringTextField or such (imho). I cant access a property of those 2 classes, because if I import the headers xcode would throw errors. I cant hook into those classes, because I dont find a appropriate method I could use for my purpose. I believe if you know how its easy-as everything..i just dont know

Comment: Hi - I'm browsing through that project and I think MCMessageBody is your friend and the stuff you are looking for are in there? Also, in MCMessage.h I see there is a NSUUID * _documentID which I think is how you get to or download the body which then maybe is a MCMessageBody? I'm just scanning this with really little knowledge and I am not sure that project will have an editor to edit the message itself with. Also, just eyeballing it, I think there are a few ...Body...Protocol's there where the message body is indented by one level that might also show how to get to the body.

Comment: Hi- thanks for sticking with me. This goes in the right direction. MCMessage is a mail core class, so this has definitely to do with sending and receiving mail. Mocking around with the properties like initial- or original message doesn't do anything. This class is undoubtedly a part of the chain of sending/receiving; it's not a part of the UI. I need to hook in this very part of the UI to set the message-body-content. The control I am looking for is most likely a webview or a wkwebview. There are alternative classes with a WK1, WK2 extension. don't know how to use them though

Comment: You're not looking for this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller?language=objc